# I need to migrate specific tags from svn to git

Tags: github, migration, repository, git-svn, svn2git

I need to migrate SVN repository to git while preserving the commit history. Problem is I have a large repository fetch file is taking lot of time. Hence if I can fetch only specific tags from SVN while migrating it to git would be very helpful.
For example I have a repository :http://svn.myhost.net/svn/code/myrepository/
myrepository/tags/: it has older versions which I don't want to include while migrating it git.

Can you please suggest to resolve this issue.

I have used git-svn to migrate the repository but it is taking lot of time.

Comment: If you need some specific tags and branches then you need to edit branches
configuration by pressing I to edit the config file. If you want to migrate
specific branches, update the first part accordingly. E.g. if you want to migrate
branchA and branchB under the branches folder, the first part should be
branches/{branchA,branchB}. Also, If you want to migrate specific tags,
update the first part accordingly. E.g. if you want to migrate tagA and tagB
under the tags folder, the first part should be tags/{tagA,tagB}